# Does the natural armor on the Devilbound creature template stack with natural armor bonuses

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I know that bonuses of the same type other than dodge do not stack. However, the natural armor increase in this template is not labeled as a bonus. Does that mean it would stack with something like the spell Transformation and/or an amulet of natural armor? Or is it just that it's simply poorly worded?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Have fun and thank you for participating.

Answer (score 4):

### Go ahead and add the [devilbound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/devilbound-creature) template's AC increase to the creature's natural armor bonus (even if one isn't listed)...

(I'm hesitant to use the word *stack* as that's usually reserved for bonuses, but, casually, yes, it stacks.)

The template [devilbound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/devilbound-creature) has the following entry:

> **Armor Class:** Natural armor improves by +4.

This isn't a *bonus* but an *improvement*. Unlike, for example, the spell [*barkskin*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/barkskin), which grants an enhancement bonus to a creature's natural armor, this modification increases the creature's existing natural armor bonus and isn't a bonus at all. This means, for example, a typical [devilbound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/devilbound-creature) [troglodyte](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/troglodyte) Ftr5's natural armor bonus is +10, and a typical [devilbound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/devilbound-creature) [human](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human) Ftr5's natural armor bonus is +4.

Because it's an improvement rather than a bonus, it's compatible with  the [*amulet of natural armor*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-natural-armor) (which grants an enhancement bonus to a creature's natural armor), but only compatible with the spell transformation if that spell's in effect when the creature gains the template, as explained below.

#### But if the creature's *already* [devilbound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/devilbound-creature), don't add the AC bonus from the spell [*transformation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation)

That is, the natural armor bonus granted by the spell [*transformation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation) will *overlap* with, not add to, the natural armor bonus of a creature *already* possessing a natural armor bonus.

This makes for the weird situation wherein if a creature casts the spell [*transformation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation) (which grants a natural armor bonus) then, while under the effect of the spell (which only lasts 1 round/level), subsequently gains the template devilbound ("Quick! Where do I sign?"), the template devilbound's improvement to natural armor improves the natural armor granted by the spell... then goes back to the new normal +4 from the template when the spell's duration expires, and, in all likelihood, the caster won't be able to get his AC that high that way again.

Comment: The template effectively creates a new creature with a higher natural armour bonus, but that new natural armour bonus is still a natural armour bonus and won't stack with transformation.
So a devilbound human is a creature with a racial +4 natural armour bonus that doesn't stack with other natural armour bonuses, while a devilbound troglodyte has a racial +10 natural armour bonus that doesn't stack with other natural armour bonuses.

Comment: @Eagle0600 The querent says in the question, "I know that bonuses of the same type other than dodge do not stack. " Do you think I should make that clear in my answer also? (That's not sarcasm; I'm just not sure what it is you'd like me to add.)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan You state that the increase from the devilbound template is compatible with both an Amulet of Natural Armour (which it is), and Transformation, which it isn't. Devilbound is a template and only effects the base creature's natural armour, it will not also increase the natural armour bonus gained from Transformation (so a Devilbound Human would gain no natural armour from Transformation).

Comment: @Eagle0600 I've not the time to fix this now, but, yes, you're correct, if the spell *transformation* is cast *after* the acquisition of the template devilbound, the spell *transformation* won't further increase the creature's natural armor. (Weirdly, a creature that casts the spell *transformation* then quickly acquires the template devilbound would see his natural armor bonus from the spell increase. So make that demonic pact *fast*, I guess. `:-)`). Thanks.

Comment: Heh, I just resolve that by assuming that templates only ever apply by modifying your race, and any bonuses granted by classes or spells or magic items are applied on top of that, not the other way around. Not an actual rule, but it's what I'd advise to avoid this kind of confusion.